# how to test play!'s controller annotated with @With annotation?

Tags: unit-testing, controller, playframework

I use interceptor annotated @With(Secure.class) that check access to a controller.
There is some regular logic performed in the controller that i want to test.

However, when i run my test (startTest) it intercepted by Secure that cause the test to fail.

```
 startTest  A play.mvc.results.Redirect has been caught, null Hide trace 
 play.mvc.results.Redirect
```

Is there any way to avoid redirection?

Comment: add class and tests, 
I have that module and don't have that problem